# We are having trouble with absorption of two elements. Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, function, element

We are korean students who are working for a project at school. We are having trouble on the absorption on two elements. We want to absorpt "carepage-navlink" and "carepage-text19" and then make them to run a function(predict()) that we made.

```
      <a href="carepage2.html" class="carepage-navlink">
        <img
          alt="Rectangle281210"
          src="public/playground_assets/rectangle281210-0sag-200h.png"
          class="carepage-rectangle28"
        />

      <a href="carepage2.html" class="carepage-text19"><span>다음</span></a>
      <img
        alt="Rectangle7129"
        src="public/playground_assets/rectangle7129-p8rj-300h.png"
        class="carepage-rectangle7"
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that you just forgot to close your first `<a>` ?

you can also add an onclick on the `<a>` tag so it looks like

```
<a onclick="function(predict)" ...
```